# How to answer on inline-query in telegram bot via golang?

Tags: go, telegram, telegram-bot

Trying to use library "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5". I have errors when i want to answer on telegram-api inline-query. How to answer?
Inline-requests is coming to my server, but code is not working, getting intro panic

```
if update.InlineQuery != nil {
        query := update.InlineQuery.Query
        fmt.Println(update.CallbackQuery.ID, update.CallbackQuery.Data)
        callback := tgbotapi.NewCallback(update.CallbackQuery.ID, update.CallbackQuery.Data)
        if _, err := bot.Request(callback); err != nil {
            panic(err) // Error here panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0xe9e3e6]
        }

        // And finally, send a message containing the data received.
        msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.ID, update.CallbackQuery.Data)
        if _, err := bot.Send(msg); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
```

I need an example to work. Don't understand this part of library at all...

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the api documentation they do list the following example (see below). TLDR, you should be responding with an InlineConfig object instead of trying to handle it like a Callback.

```
if update.InlineQuery == nil {
        continue
    }

    article := NewInlineQueryResultArticle(update.InlineQuery.ID, "Echo", update.InlineQuery.Query)
    article.Description = update.InlineQuery.Query

    inlineConf := InlineConfig{
        InlineQueryID: update.InlineQuery.ID,
        IsPersonal:    true,
        CacheTime:     0,
        Results:       []interface{}{article},
    }

    if _, err := bot.Request(inlineConf); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

I followed through with the example for a case where I wanted to return multiple results as Articles given a user's query and it worked brilliantly for me :)

Reference:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5@v5.5.1#InlineConfig